# Scrollable div for mobile websites

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using the age old trick to make a div scrollable like below:

```
<div style="height: 100px; overflow: scroll;">
   Messages within div.
   Messages within div.
   Messages within div.
   Messages within div.
</div>
```

But the scroll bar is never shown on the iPad.

Does anybody have an idea how to add a scroll bar or at least some sort of visual indication that the div is scrollable for the iPad?

Comment: Maybe a gradient PNG to "fade out" the content at the bottom, indicating there's more?

Comment: And if it fades from transparent into the same color as the background, it would degrade gracefully if there isn't enough content to scroll...

Comment: The lack of scroll bars is an iOS thing, you might want to take a look at the [iScrollView](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) plugin, but that might be overkill for what you need. I thought I remembered a plugin that does just add the scroll bars but I can't find it now.